# Removing tables and its text in a pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pdf

I am writing a python code to extract the text using PyMUpdf, when there are tables and images  in the pdf I am getting the text inside that as well, I do not what that text which is inside table, I tried all possible way as per my knowledge but no success, Please help me to extract text without tables or images and without the content inside them

Thanks
Vinay

I tried using expressions, I tried giving table size etc.

Comment: The problem is that every text on a PDF page is just text, including text in tables. If you somehow know or can detect the table's rectangle, you can (temporarily) erase the table content just before your text extraction, using redaction annotations. If there are **images**, you do not have a problem, do you? Their content will not deliver text! But maybe you are dealing with OCRed text? Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

In a page,you can extract different component,such as text,images,tables with the bbox(e.g. x0,y0,x1,y0);you can make sure the diff component by the positions so that discard the component you don't need.